# node.js exporst functions from const

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to export function without many times of declaration of exports? Like below I straigth away export a function.

```
exports.send = function(abc, def) { }
```

Is below not the same with above statement?

```
const send = (abc, def) => {}
exports.send = send
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is below not the same with above statement?

No. Your first one is a traditional function, your second is an arrow function. So either:

```
exports.send = function(abc, def) { };
```

and

```
const send = function(abc, def) {};
exports.send = send;
```

or

```
exports.send = (abc, def) => { };
```

and

```
const send = (abc, def) => {};
exports.send = send;
```

Other than that, they're largely the same, except that of course your module has an in-scope constant called `send` in the second example.